# Database choices for big data

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, distributed, bigdata

I have many text files, their total size is about 300GB ~ 400GB. They are all in this format

```
key1 value_a
key1 value_b
key1 value_c
key2 value_d
key3 value_e
....
```

each line is composed by a key and a value. I want to create a database which can let me query all value of a key. For example, when I query key1, value_a, value_b and value_c are returned.

First of all, inserting all these files into the database is a big problem. I try to insert a few GBs size chunk to MySQL MyISAM table with LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. But it appears MySQL can't utilize multicores for inserting data. It's as slow as hell. So, I think MySQL is not a good choice here for so many records.

Also, I need to update or recreate the database periodically, weekly, or even daily if possible, therefore, insertion speed is important for me.

It's not possible for a single node to do the computing and insertion efficiently, to be efficient, I think it's better to perform the insertion in different nodes parallely.

For example,

```
node1 -> compute and store 0-99999.txt
node2 -> compute and store 10000-199999.txt
node3 -> compute and store 20000-299999.txt
....
```

So, here comes the first criteria.

**Criteria 1. Fast insertion speed in distributed batch manner.**

Then, as you can see in the text file example, it's better to provide multiple same key to different values. Just like key1 maps to value_a/value_b/value_c in the example.

**Criteria 2. Multiple keys are allowed**

Then, I will need to query keys in the database. No relational or complex join query is required, all I need is simple key/value querying. The important part is that multiple key to same value

**Criteria 3. Simple and fast key value querying.**

I know there are HBase/Cassandra/MongoDB/Redis.... and so on, but I'm not familiar with all of them, not sure which one fits my needs. So, the question is - what database to use? If none of them fits my needs, I even plan to build my own, but it takes efforts :/

Thanks.

Comment: Don't build your own. Doesn't matter how good you are, are you *sure* you're as good as all those people that do nothing but this all the time? With support, with users, with testing?

Comment: Of course, I'm not as good as all those people. I don't want to rebuild the wheel, too. But if no wheel out there fits my needs, I have to build one. :S

Comment: No, for something as major as a database storage engine, you are *always* better off adjusting your requirements slightly, or dealing with the quirks. Google didn't create their own storage system for their data, they patched MySQL a bit. Don't make the mistake of thinking your problem is unique.

Comment: It's not really a programming question. Try asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cylindric, I disagree. Oracle and such may be very complex, but an immutable key/value database is not. You don't have to be afraid of it. Google did create their own storage system(s!) for their data (Bigtable, some of the guts of which turned into open source LevelDB; Spanner; and many others), and you can use a small portion of LevelDB to solve this problem. That portion is surprisingly simple; there's no reason you can't achieve a good working understanding of the code and data structures involved.

Comment: Actually, I have already built a simple prototype. It sorts those input files at each node and store them locally. To query, I use binary search. Send query request to every nodes. Then nodes open all local files, seek too middle of the file, and see current line bigger or small then target. It works, barely works. But, with multiple IO seeking, it is slow. And still need lots effort to make it work better. Currently, I'm looking into Hadoop & HBase, they fits my needs, but annoying to configure and very complex. I will give LevelDB a shot when I have spare time. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. The LevelDB tables will help with the seeking. Is the sharding practical? If you can send a query request to just the one node responsible for the key instead of to all nodes, you can save a factor of N.

Comment: @Victor Lin So, Victor, any post-fact experience you want to share? I might be doing something similar  with few tens of millions entries to search in ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a lot of systems that would fit your needs. Your requirements make things pleasantly easy in a couple ways:

- Because you don't need any cross-key operations, you could use multiple databases, dividing keys between them via hash or range sharding. This is an easy way to solve the lack of parallelism that you observed with MySQL and probably would observe with a lot of other database systems.
- Because you never do any online updates, you can just build an immutable database in bulk and then query it for the rest of the day/week. I'd expect you'd get a lot better performance this way.

I'd be inclined to build a set of hash-sharded [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) tables. That is, I wouldn't use an actual `leveldb::DB` which supports a more complex data structure (a stack of tables and a log) so that you can do online updates; instead, I'd directly use `leveldb::Table` and `leveldb::TableBuilder` objects (no log, only one table for a given key). This is a very efficient format for querying. And if your input files are already sorted like in your example, the table building will be extremely efficient as well. You can achieve whatever parallelism you desire by increasing the number of shards - if you're using a 16-core, 16-disk machine to build the database, then use at least 16 shards, all generated in parallel. If you're using 16 16-core, 16-disk machines, at least 256 shards. If you have a lot fewer disks than cores as many people do these days, try both, but you may find fewer shards are better to avoid seeks. If you're careful, I think you can basically max out the disk throughput while building tables, and that's saying a lot as I'd expect the tables to be noticeably smaller than your input files due to the key prefix compression (and optionally Snappy block compression). You'll mostly avoid seeks because aside from a relatively small index that you can typically buffer in RAM, the keys in the leveldb tables are stored in the same order as you read them from the input files, assuming again that your input files are already sorted. If they're not, you may want enough shards that you can sort a shard in RAM then write it out, perhaps processing shards more sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using SSDB(https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), a leveldb server that suitable for storing collections of data.

You can store the data in maps:

```
ssdb->hset(key1, value1)
ssdb->hset(key1, value2)
...

list = ssdb->hscan(key1, 1000);
// now list = [value1, value2, ...]
```

SSDB is fast(half the speed of Redis, 30000 insertions per second), it is a network wrapper of leveldb, one-line installation and startup. Its clients include PHP, C++, Python, Java, Lua, ...

Answer (score 0):

The traditional answer would be to use Oracle if you have the big bucks, or PostgreSQL if you don't. However, I'd suggest you also look at solutions like mongoDb which I found to be blazing fast and will also accomodate a scenario where your schema is not fixed and can change across your data.

Comment: Really? A "my RDBMS is faster than yours" answer? Spending more money doesn't magically make this stuff faster.

Comment: I have a very limited budget. I know MongoDB is fast, but I have no idea how it performs at 300GB ~ 400GB scale. I know it supports auto sharding, but how about inserting 300GB record into MongoDB?

Comment: There's definitely no need to spend any money on software, particularly software whose complexity is to meet requirements you don't have (ACID, complex SQL queries). However, you could buy something to make it magically faster: enough SSD and/or RAM to avoid hitting disk. A 512 GB SSD at crucial.com costs $611.79 right now, much less than the most basic Oracle license I think...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already familiar with MySQL, I suggest trying all MySQL options before moving to a new system. 
Many bigdata systems are tuned for very specific problems but don't fare well in areas that are taken for granted from a RDBMS. Also, most applications need regular RDBMS features alongside bigdata features. So moving to a new system may create new problems.

Also consider the software ecosystem, community support and knowledge base available around the system of your choice.

Coming back to the solution, how many rows would be there in the database? This is an important metric. I am assuming more than 100 million.

Try [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html). It can help a lot. The fact that your select criteria is simple and you don't require joins only make things better.

Postgres has  a nice way of handling partitions. It requires more code to get up and running but gives an amazing control. Unlike MySQL, Postgres does not have a hard limit on number of partitions. Partitions in Postgres are regular tables. This gives you much more control over indexing, searching, backup, restore, parallel data access etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/).  You can store multiple values against a key, by using columns.  Unlike RDBMS, you don't need to have fixed set of columns in each row, but can have arbitrary number of columns for a row.  Since you query data by a key (row-key in HBase parlance), you can retrieve all the values for a given key by reading values of all the columns in that row.

HBase also concept of retention period, so you can decide which columns live for how long. Hence, the data can get cleaned up on its own, as per need basis.  There are some interesting techniques people have employed to utilize the retention periods.

HBase is quite scalable, and supports very fast reads and writes.

Answer (score 0):

InfoBright maybe is a good choice.